# Understanding underlying type of C/C++ bit fields

Tags: c++, c, struct, bit-fields, underlyingtype

When reading [Microsoft Docs on C++ Bit Fields 1st code paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cpp-bit-fields?view=msvc-160#code-try-0), the sentence ‘Note that `nYear` is 8 bits long and would overflow the word boundary of the declared type’ is a bit difficult to understand.

```cpp
// bit_fields1.cpp
// compile with: /LD
struct Date {
   unsigned short nWeekDay  : 3;    // 0..7   (3 bits)
   unsigned short nMonthDay : 6;    // 0..31  (6 bits)
   unsigned short nMonth    : 5;    // 0..12  (5 bits)
   unsigned short nYear     : 8;    // 0..100 (8 bits)
};
```

My understanding of it is that an ‘underlying type’ is some sort of a ‘container type’ where the number of ‘declared bit fields’ must be less than or equal to the ‘bits of container type’. Also ‘continuous bit field declarations’ with the same ‘underlying type’ will always combine if possible except a `(underlying type) : 0;` is encountered.

```cpp
// bit_fields2.cpp
// compile with: /LD
struct Date {
   unsigned nWeekDay  : 3;    // 0..7   (3 bits)
   unsigned nMonthDay : 6;    // 0..31  (6 bits)
   unsigned           : 0;    // Force alignment to next boundary.
   unsigned nMonth    : 5;    // 0..12  (5 bits)
   unsigned nYear     : 8;    // 0..100 (8 bits)
};
```

In this case, the ‘Force alignment to next boundary indicator’ is a separator between 2 `container types`.

In the 1st case, ‘overflow the word boundary of the declared type’ only means there is not enough bits in the 1st ‘container type’ to hold 8 bits, if the `nYear` line is changed to `unsigned short nYear : 2;`, then the size of `Date` will be exactly 2 (tested with VS2019).

Is this kind of understanding a correct approach? Or are there any glitches in terminology? Comments are appreciated.

Comment: The standard uses the term "storage-unit" (MS simply cannot use terms from a technical standard but _must_ invent their own) for an abstract chunk of memory inside a bit-field, which in turn likely corresponds to an aligned chunk. All of this nonsense originates from bit-fields not being well-defined by the standard, so things like bit order, misalignment, padding, mixing different types etc is completely compiler-specific. The general advise is to never use bit-fields for any purpose, it's a broken part of the language.

Comment: I would be surprised if `: 0` was defined in all compilers.

Comment: Given "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type.", Using `unsigned short` for a bit field, it not portable.

Comment: @Neil In C17, "As a special case, a bit-field structure member with a width of 0 indicates that no further bit-field is to be packed into the unit in which the previous bit-field, if any, was placed..".  Perhaps a 0 width was defined in earlier versisons.

Comment: steve C specifies "An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined.".  If portable code is desired, avoid bit fields.  If code does not need portablity, why does the memory layout manner?

Comment: @Neil Just tested, at least it is supported on g++ and MSVC 2019

Comment: I was mistaken; it is legit. @chux-ReinstateMonica It also appears in ISO9899.

Comment: "if the nYear line is changed to unsigned short nYear : 2;, then the size of Date will be exactly 2" --> not always.   Other sizes possible depending on implementation details.  But _why_ do you care about "Understanding underlying type"? If really space concerned, use `uint16_t` and form helper functions to set and read the fields.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica According to the [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), short types have at least 16 bits. The same goes to int for 32 bits. Yeah `uint16_t` is more of an correct type than `unsigned short` in the Microsoft Docs.

Comment: @StevenLiang " The same goes to int for 32 bits." --> `int` are at least 16 bit, just like `short`.